# Having problems while using electron-reload module

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am getting the following error while trying to use the [electron-reload](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload) module. (which I am not able to understand)

```
Error: Cannot find module 'app'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\path\Electron\music-player\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.as
ar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\path\Electron\music-player\node_modules\electron-reload\main.js:1:90)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

And the `main.js` has the following for usage of the module

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
require('electron-reload')(__dirname+'/public')
```

Can anyone guide me how to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to update `electron-reload` to v1.0.0 or later, the release notes claim it was updated to support Electron v1.0.0+.

Comment: It looks like the OP is referring to the [electron-reload](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload) library, not [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild).

Comment: @rob3c Oops, that was a typo on my part, I was actually talking about `electron-reload`. Fixed now, thanks!